# get sum of count of count postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate

I have two tables `jobs` and `users`.
Users has a one-to-many relationship with jobs.

I want to segment users into groups of jobs_done. 
In other words, how many users did 1 job, 2 jobs, 3 jobs, etc
The below query does that. However, I would like to lump together all users that have done 3 or more jobs into one group.

Here is the query I currently have

```
select
  jobs_done,
   count(1) as number_of_users
  from ( select 
     u.id,
      count(*) as jobs_done
   from jobs j
  JOIN users u on j.user_id = u.id 
  group by  u.id ) a
group by jobs_done
```

Current Output:

```
times_used  number_of_users  
1           255  
2           100  
3           30  
4           10  
5           9
```

Desired Output:

```
times_used  number_of_users  
1           255  
2           100  
3+          49
```

Comment: You should have posted your schema and it is not entirely clear what you want as output.  So showing us a sample output would help.

Comment: Can the same `jobs_done` be recorded in `jobs` for the same `user_id` more than once?

Comment: added detail for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to group values 3+ into one large group. This should work:

```
select
    case 
       when jobs_done >= 3 then '3+' 
       else cast(jobs_done as varchar(5)) 
    end as jobs_done,
    count(1) as number_of_users
from ( 
    select 
       u.id,
       count(*) as jobs_done
    from jobs j
    join users u on j.user_id = u.id 
    group by  u.id 
) a
group by case when jobs_done >= 3 then '3+' 
             else cast(jobs_done as varchar(5)) 
         end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can group by basically everything. this is a simplistic example:

```
test=# SELECT CASE WHEN x < 4 THEN x::text ELSE '4+' END AS y, 
              count(*) 
       FROM generate_series(1, 10) AS x 
       GROUP BY y 
       ORDER BY 1;
 y  | count 
----+-------
 1  |     1
 2  |     1
 3  |     1
 4+ |     7
(4 rows)
```